# How to extract a particular part of string and replace with the same extracted value but in different case - using java

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

1. My Input **t%60hiag%2Fra%2Cjan**
2. I want this to be converted to **t%60hiag%2fra%2cjan**

I would like to replace %2F with %2f. i.e. any number between 0-9 followed by upper case alphabet from A-F should be converted to lower case alphabet.

I was able to extract and replace with a generic string. But I need help in replacing the extracted string to lower case.

```
  private static String urlEncodeLowerCase(String stringInput)
  {
    stringInput = stringInput.replaceAll("%[0-9]{1}[A-F]{1}", "T");  
    return stringInput;
  }
```

Above code will extract and replace the extracted string with "T" but I want something similar

```
stringInput = stringInput.replaceAll("%[0-9]{1}[A-F]{1}", "%[0-9]{1}[A-Z]{1}".toLowerCase);
```

Above code won't work. This is just to make you understand my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
private static String urlEncodeLowerCase(String stringInput) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("%[0-9]{1}[A-Z]{1}");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(stringInput);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String s = matcher.group();
        stringInput = stringInput.replace(s, s.toLowerCase());
    }
    return stringInput;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

You should use regexp to match parts of string you want to change. After that you should iterate through the all matches and rebuild the string with converting matching parts and leaving without changes all other. Take a look how Pattern, Matcher and StringBuilder classes works.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Matcher#appendReplacement`. As per [Java *Matcher* class docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html):

> The [appendReplacement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/re) and [appendTail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendTail(java.lang.StringBuffer)) methods can be used in tandem in order to collect the result into an existing string buffer

See this Java demo:

```
String s = "Some Text %0A";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("%[0-9][A-Z]");
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(result, m.group().toLowerCase());
}
m.appendTail(result);
System.out.println(result.toString());
// => Some Text %0a
```

If you want to make sure there is a word boundary after the uppercase letter, use `"%[0-9][A-Z]\\b"` pattern.